# Use Pandas to round based on another column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe where 1 column is a list of values and another is the number of digits I need to round to. It looks like this:

```
  ValueToPlot  B_length
0       13.80       1.0
1       284.0       0.0
2         5.9       0.0
3        1.38       1.0
4       287.0       0.0
```

I am looking for an output that looks like this:

```
  ValueToPlot  B_length  Rounded
0       13.80       1.0     13.8
1       284.0       0.0      284
2         5.9       0.0        6
3        1.38       1.0      1.4
4       287.0       0.0      287
```

Lastly, I would like the Rounded column to be in a string format, so the final result would be:

```
  ValueToPlot  B_length  Rounded
0       13.80       1.0   '13.8'
1       284.0       0.0    '284'
2         5.9       0.0      '6'
3        1.38       1.0    '1.4'
4       287.0       0.0    '287'
```

I have attempted to use `apply` function in Pandas but have not been successful. I would prefer to avoid looping if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use chained `format`s
`'{{:0.{}f}}'.format(3)` evaluates to `'{:0.3f}'`.  The double `'{{}}'` tells `format` to escape the `'{}'`.  Then `'{:0.3f}'.format(1)` evaluates to `1.000`.  We can capture this concept by chaining.

```
f = lambda x: '{{:0.{}f}}'.format(int(x[1])).format(x[0])

df.assign(Rounded=df.apply(f, 1))

   ValueToPlot  B_length Rounded
0        13.80       1.0    13.8
1       284.00       0.0     284
2         5.90       0.0       6
3         1.38       1.0     1.4
4       287.00       0.0     287
```

---

A little more explicit with the column names

```
f = lambda x: '{{:0.{}f}}'.format(int(x['B_length'])).format(x['ValueToPlot'])

df.assign(Rounded=df.apply(f, 1))

   ValueToPlot  B_length Rounded
0        13.80       1.0    13.8
1       284.00       0.0     284
2         5.90       0.0       6
3         1.38       1.0     1.4
4       287.00       0.0     287
```

---

I generally like to use `assign` as it produces a copy of the data frame with a new column attached.  I can edit the original data frame

```
f = lambda x: '{{:0.{}f}}'.format(int(x[1])).format(x[0])

df['Rounded'] = df.apply(f, 1)
```

Or I can use `assign` with an actual dictionary

```
f = lambda x: '{{:0.{}f}}'.format(int(x[1])).format(x[0])

df.assign(**{'Rounded': df.apply(f, 1)})
```

Comment: I like this solution but is there a way to use a string in the place of `Rounded` when you use the `assign` function? I actually have this column name referenced from an Excel spreadsheet.

Comment: Is there a benefit to using `assign` or is this a personal preference?

Comment: Both, I usually avoid in place edits to data frames.  I like to assign back to variable names.  `assign` allows me to do that.  I'd also be happy to use `join` like this `df.join(df.apply(f, 1).rename('Rounded'))`

Answer (score 1):

A little long ... but work

```
df.apply(lambda x : str(round(x['ValueToPlot'],int(x['B_length']))) if x['B_length']>0 else str(int(round(x['ValueToPlot'],int(x['B_length'])))),axis=1)
Out[1045]: 
0    13.8
1     284
2       6
3     1.4
4     287
dtype: object
```

Comment: This snippet only shows 1 and 0 values in `B_length` but this can be any value really. Can you produce a generalized solution?

Comment: @Rookie just change ==1 to >0